# Excel 2010 MATCH function returns an error in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

When I enter the following formula in a cell it returns TRUE, but when I enter this into a new conditional formatting rule, it tells me I have an error.

This is the formula:

`=ISERROR(MATCH(Table2[Website];Table13;0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDIRECT
`=ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("Table2[Website]");INDIRECT("Table13");0))`

[Similar Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20368050/4605204)

> INDIRECT():Returns the reference specified by a text string.
>   References are immediately evaluated

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know why `INDIRECT` is required here?